# OOP: class without static members or complete redesign

Tags: c++, oop

I am teaching a c++ course, and in one of the project, the students are required to write the code of a Robot class.

The Robot constructor is fixed and the instances are created from a function that the students can not modify. However, the rest of the class design is left as an exercise.

I want to make sure the Robot instances can not share information between each other easily. If a student wants to share information, he can create static members of the class or use static variables in the implementation of the class to store information about each instances.
There might also be other ways to take advantage of the language to "cheat" (e.g writing in a file, using sockets...).

Is there any way to check for this kind of abuse (e.g the presence of a static member) ? I am open to any suggestion at this point. 
Should I consider a complete redesign so that each instances "lives in a completely different world" that prevents them from communicating with each other ?
Is it a fundamentally impossible problem to prevent, and should I just warn them of the severe implications of such behavior ?

Thanks.

**EDIT:**
The reason I am asking this question is not to ease the grading. I plan on creating an automated platform where the students can submit their code and have them compete with each others. In this scenario, I won't be able to read and validate the code before it is posted.
I would like to prevent "easy" abuse (e.g static members) and think that more involved abuse won't be so common.

Thus my question would really be : is there a way to programmatically prevent students from having static members (template hack or something) or should I redesign the classes. Thanks

Comment: `grep static code.cpp`

Comment: Yes I already thought of this :)

Comment: Control of access to class members is at the class level, not individual objects.    Since you are teaching the course, simply state that students will be marked down if they use anything other than non-static members to communicate between instances of `Robot`.   Of course, that requires you to examine the code, rather than simply having the code checked automatically.

Comment: There are other ways of sharing data without static members.  Will you also grade down `std::shared_ptr, or a common base class`, if you find it in the code?

Comment: Yes a common base is another way to share information that won't be tolerated. I am not sure how a shared_ptr could be used to achieve this ? Each instance won't be aware of the other instances unless combined with some static variables. Can you elaborate ?

Comment: @elvadrias: `struct A { shared_ptr<Data> data; };` Now multiple `A`s can share access to the same `Data`.

Comment: In this example `data` is not available to another `A`, unless a `A` is made aware of another `A`. Unless `data` is itself static, or `A` uses static members or variables to keep track of other instances of `A`, I don't think it is possible to have access to the `data` field from another instance. The fact that `data` is a `shared_ptr` or a raw pointer is irrelevant here, isn't it ?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to check for this kind of abuse (e.g the presence of a static member)?

**Yes: read the code.**

There may be some way to automatically prohibit this with language hacks and/or running a parser over the resulting code. But in general these solutions will be *way* overkill if they work properly at all.

So just do what we do in industry: use your eyes to review the code, and mark accordingly! Hopefully you're already reading the code before deciding what mark to give the student, so this should be no skin off your teeth.

Just remember to tell your students in advance that you don't want to see such hackery.

Comment: I updated the question ! My goal is not to simplify the grading but to really prevent the easiest case of abuses.

Comment: @elvadrias: My answer stands. Simply read the code. I'm not going to pretend that I am 100% sure there's no way to do what you're proposing automatically, _but_ I do know that it'll be (a) horrible, and (b) not worthwhile. I appreciate what you're trying to achieve but, honestly, you're really going to have to bring the human cognitive faculties to bear on any problem like this.

Comment: Yes, I agree that checking exhaustively for each kind of abuse automatically might be overkill. However some of the given suggestions are very simple and might be enough to discourage the smarta**es. In any case, the code will be checked when grading, but not when submitted online, and I don't want the project to become a troll fest ;)

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to check for this kind of abuse (e.g the presence of a static member) ?

Kind of. Programmatically within C++, no - C++ doesn't have reflection, so there's no way to write the type trait `has_static_member<T>`.

What you basically would need is your own C++ parser to generate an AST that you can then walk to determine if a `static` member exists. I would not recommend trying to write your own C++ AST parser. Thankfully, you could use [clang's](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/IntroductionToTheClangAST.html). Which can also be used [in Python](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/07/03/parsing-c-in-python-with-clang). And now it's just a matter of figuring out how to use that to give you the answer you want.

As an example,

```
class Robot {
public:
    Robot();
    void foo();
private:
    static int bar;
    double quux;
};
```

when run through the `ast-dump` command gives me:

```
|-CXXRecordDecl 0x491c9d8 <main.cpp:1:5, line:8:5> line:1:11 class Robot definition
| |-CXXRecordDecl 0x491caf0 <col:5, col:11> col:11 implicit referenced class Robot
| |-AccessSpecDecl 0x491cb80 <line:2:5, col:11> col:5 public
| |-CXXConstructorDecl 0x491cc50 <line:3:9, col:15> col:9 Robot 'void (void)'
| |-CXXMethodDecl 0x496f900 <line:4:9, col:18> col:14 foo 'void (void)'
| |-AccessSpecDecl 0x496f9a8 <line:5:5, col:12> col:5 private
| |-VarDecl 0x496f9e0 <line:6:9, col:20> col:20 bar 'int' static
| `-FieldDecl 0x496fa50 <line:7:9, col:16> col:16 quux 'double'
```

So you're looking for `VarDecl`s that are class members (since the non-static members are `FieldDecl`s).

Comment: Thanks, this is a very simple approach that I could include in a pre-processing script. This seems to be more robust than a simple grep static.